# How to customize the dropdownlist in flutter , like flikart dropdownlist

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want to dropdownlist but i'm not able to do following things.

- change the width of the dropdownbutton
- make the dropdownlist to start at the dropdownbutton's height , not above it as default
- adjust the height of the dropdownmenuitem

Want i want is

[image]    [image]

What i have is

[image] [image]

The code goes like

```
                                                child: ButtonTheme(
                                                  alignedDropdown: true,
                                                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                                        // isDense: true,
                                                        // isExpanded: true,
                                                        itemHeight: null,
                                                        // menuMaxHeight: 10,
                                                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                                        elevation: 0,
                                                        value: selectedQuantity,
                                                        selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                                          return _dropDownQuantities.map<Widget>((String item) {
                                                            return Container(
                                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                              // color: Colors.green,
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                'Qty: $item',
                                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                                              ),
                                                            );
                                                          }).toList();
                                                        },
                                                        items: _dropDownQuantities.map((e) {
                                                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
                                                            child: Container(
                                                                child: Column(
                                                              children: [Container(child: Text(e))],
                                                            )),
                                                            value: e,
                                                          );
                                                        }).toList(),
                                                        hint: Text("Qty: 1 "),
                                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            selectedQuantity = value!;
                                                          });
                                                        }),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) to achieve that.

1. Use `buttonWidth` property to change the width of the dropdownbutton.
2. Use `offset` property to change the position of the dropdown menu. You should add button's height to the dy offset to make it start at the dropdownbutton's height like this: Offset(0.0, "button's height")
3. Use `itemHeight` property to adjust the height of the dropdownmenuitem.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you ! , Do you know to stop animation of the menuItems rendering, if the menuItems contains 1,2,3,4,5 then as of now by default 1 2 3 4 5 are displayed in a sequence with the animation, I want every number to be loaded at once , Is it possible ?

Comment: You'll need to edit the package file. Replace the lines at 182,183 with this:

    opacity = CurvedAnimation(parent: widget.route.animation!, curve: Interval(0.0, 0.0));

Also, to stop the animation of the menu itself update the curve values at lines 273 and 278 to 0.0.